# What is the universal/fine uniformity on a topological group?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, uniform-spaces

I'm aware that every topological group is uniformizable: given a neighborhood $U\in\mathcal N(e)$ of the identity, the set $D_U=\{\langle x,y\rangle:x^{-1}y\in U\text{ and }xy^{-1}\in U\}$ is an entourage of the diagonal and $\mathbb D=\{D_U:U\in\mathcal N(e)\}$ is a base for a uniformity compatible with the topology.

Is this $\mathbb D$ a base for the universal/fine uniformity (the union of all compatible uniformities) on a topological group? If not, when is it? And if not, is there a similar algebraic characterization of the universal/fine uniformity?

Comment: With respect to the canonical uniformity, $\mathbb Q$ is not complete, but with respect to the finest uniformity it is (as for every Tychonoff paracompact space).

Comment: Or: I think in most cases (e.g., $\mathbb R$), the finest uniformity does not have a countable base.

Comment: According to [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-9/issue-2/Spaces-whose-finest-uniformity-is-metric/pjm/1103039277.pdf), theorem 2, for a non-discrete, metrizable topological group, the canonical uniformity coincides with the finest uniformity, if and only if it is compact.